# Is there a way to reset your computer enough to let you create a New Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id, macos

Is there a way to reset your computer enough to let you create a New Apple ID with out getting the message that you have to create one by going to the iCloud.com?

Comment: wut ???? you lost me there

Comment: how about you create new user, which would not have Apple ID by default

Comment: I get a pop up message that says - iCloud error This Mac can no longer be used to create a new Apple ID. Create a new Apple ID at appleid.apple.com. That is after creating a new user during set up.

Comment: Why can’t you just use iCloud

Comment: I want to reset my computers settings that hold onto not letting me do so.

Comment: How many Apple ID accounts have you created using this Mac?  There are limits to how many you can create per device.  Those limits are not saved in the computer settings.  They are tracked server side.  Contact Apple support to see if they'll grant an exception to allow an additional account to be created.  Or you could create it using a different Apple device.

Comment: Extending @LaterSkater's comment: the limit is actually on the number of iCloud accounts (where "iCloud account" = Apple ID with iCloud services activated). You can create as many Apple IDs *without* iCloud services, but the Setup Assistant prompt to "create/use/whatever your Apple ID" also tries to set up iCloud services, and that can run into the limit. BTW last time I tested, the limit was 3 iCloud accounts per device (Mac, iPhone, or iPad).

Comment: I have over time crated a bit of them. I will contact apple and see if access control settings are controlled to a devices AppleID.

Comment: Wait . so you are saying the limit was 3 iCloud accounts per device. How can I check that on my computer in the Disk Utility? I am still figuring out users and groups so that I can understand what is going on in Disk Utility, because it says I have 4 volumes and is it possible I have different iCloud accounts in them?

Comment: Gordon Davisson is correct.  The limit specifically applies to creating new iCloud accounts.  3 iCloud account creations per device.  That information is view-able by Apple on their side.  There isn't a place in the computer settings to check how many accounts have been created.  Users and Groups is for managing local user accounts on the computer.  Disk Utility and disk volumes have nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: @LisaAnn You could try logging into all your various user accounts on the Mac, opening System Preferences -> iCloud pane, and seeing what (if any) iCloud account they're connected to. But that tells you which iCloud accounts *are currently in use* on that Mac, not which iCloud accounts *were created on* that Mac. If you created iCloud accounts on that Mac and then stopped using them... there's not necessarily any way to find them. OTOH, there might be accounts you created somewhere else (have an iPhone?) and just used on the Mac. The limit applies *only* to iCloud account creation, not use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to reset your computer to create a new Apple ID account.  Simply sign out of the existing Apple ID.  Once signed out you will have a login that will allow you to create a new account. If you don't want to sign out you could also create a new user account for your computer, sign into that new user account, then create a new Apple ID in system preferences under it.  You can also use iTunes or the Apple ID website to make a new Apple ID account.  To create the iCloud portion of the account you have to sign into iCloud with the Apple ID using an Apple device.